# How to make a table cell be linked and with background-color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am using javascript to dynamically color table cells. I would like the cells to have a background-color for the entire cell, and the text inside should be hyperlinked. I don't think I care if the entire cell is part of the hyperlink

One try is:

```
<td><a class="score" href="#">cell text</a></td>
<td><a href="#">cell text</a></td>
<td><a class="score" href="#">cell text</a></td>
...
...
<script>
  var colorScore = document.getElementsByClassName('score');
  for (i=0; i < colorScore.length; i++) {
    colorScore[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
</script>
```

This gives me a cell where only the text is hyperlinked and only the text has a background-color. I also tried putting `class="score"` with the `<td>` instead of the `<a>` but that did not give any background-color (but obviously kept the hyperlink).  Finally, I tried it with the `<a>` surrounding the `<td>` but this gives me neither a hyperlink nor a background-color, I believe this is not allowed in html.

I'm also using Bootstrap 5 but I don't think it offers any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment just the a element is getting a background. What we need is its parent element to get the background.

This snippet does that, and also for the sake of the demo it gives a padding to each td so we can see the cell is covered in red, not just the text.

```js
var colorScore = document.getElementsByClassName('score');
for (i = 0; i < colorScore.length; i++) {
  colorScore[i].parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="score" href="#">cell text</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">cell text</a></td>
    <td><a class="score" href="#">cell text</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting this @traktor. There isn't enough in the question to know why the whole cell isn't clickable. If the padding is put on the a element then the whole cell will be clickable, but we aren't told if there is other stuff in there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try storing the hyperlink target in a custom attribute and intercepting a `click` event that assigns that value to `window.location`.

We can use event delegation like so:

```js
var colorScore = document.getElementsByClassName('score');
for (i = 0; i < colorScore.length; i++) {
  colorScore[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let closest = e.target.closest('.score');
  if(closest) location = closest.dataset.href;
})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="score" data-href="https://stacksnippets.net"><a>cell text</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">cell text</a></td>
    <td class="score" data-href="https://stacksnippets.net"><a>cell text</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```